# Appropriate title/subject when writing to someone who got injured in a car accident

Tags: word-choice, email

Recently a professor in my department got injured in a car accident and I want to write him a sympathy email. However, I don't know how to choose the title/subject for the email. Can I simply write "condolence"? (Is it only used for those who passed away?) If it is okay to use "condolence", are there any alternative to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condolence is usually reserved for expressions of sympathy for the bereaved. Cambridge Dictionary defines condolence as "sympathy and sadness for the family or close friends of a person who has recently died, or an expression of this, especially in written form". For an injury, another word would be better. Sympathy might be a good candidate. In general, genuine messages of this type do not strive for dictionary correctness; we are showing sympathy, not showing off our command of language. I suggest a simple subject line like "Sorry to hear about your accident".